# Docker, how to COPY docker-specific versions of files to WORKDIR

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Can Docker's `COPY` or `RUN cp` be used in a Dockerfile to overwrite a default config file with a docker-specific version of the file?

In a Rails project, our config folder has multiple versions of database.yml for different environments:

```
# projectname/config/
database.yml # an unused default placeholder
database_for_docker_2.yml
database_for_vagrant.yml
```

For different dev environments (vagrant+virtualbox vs docker) during initialization of the machine/container we copy the appropriate version of the .yml to database.yml

In the Dockerfile, after this section:

```
WORKDIR /my_app
RUN bundle install 
COPY . /my_app
```

we tried:

> RUN cp ./config/database_docker_2.yml   /my_app/config/database.yml

but the file does not seem to be copied, the default version of database.yml is used when we spin up the container.

we then tried:

> COPY ./config/database_docker_2.yml   /my_app/config/database.yml

the file still does not seem to be copied, the default version of the file gets used when we spin up the container.

What DOES work is adding another entry to the volume section of docker-compose.yml specifically for that one file:

```
    volumes:
      - .:/my_app
      - ./config/database_docker_2.yml:/my_app/config/database.yml
```

but we prefer to manage the placement of env-specific versions of files in the Dockerfile (as opposed to littering the docker-compose.yml with such env-specific files)

Comment: When using the COPY in Dockerfile, are you creating a new image? COPY and RUN will only work when creating images, not when running containers.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using your latest built image for the container?

Answer (score 1):

The command `COPY ./config/database_docker_2.yml /my_app/config/database.yml` probably works, there is no reason it shouldn't assuming the source exists.

What I suspect happens, is that when you are testing it, you already have a volume with `.:/my_app`, which then shows you the **local** folder, and not the in-container folder.

Run it without the volume, and I believe you will in fact see that it copied it into the container, as you intended.

On a side note:

If you are not yet locked in your way of handling this multiple database config, I would consider re-evaluating your situation, and trying to find a solution that does not require you to change `database.yml` for each environment. One way, would be to have the `database.yml` use an environment variable (usually `DATABASE_URL`) and then you have one `docker-compose` for all, and one `database.yml` for all, and you only configure environment with environment variables.